# SQL Server 2008 SA account locked

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Trying to access SQL Server 2008 database of production server but admin and SA account was not accepting it. 
After trying several time SA account is locked. How to unlock it without any production server issue?

Thanks

Comment: There are three different methods as listed here so give the first one a try if you can at least: http://www.wikihow.com/Reset-SA-Password-in-Sql-Server

Comment: Did you find the link useful in getting your problem resolve? If you have local admin access to the server SQL is installed, you can gain access accordingly. Let me know how it goes with this issue you asked about help in getting resolved.